# Manipulating data from 2 maps to create a 3rd map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-8

```
Map<String, List<myStruct>> map1 = ...;  
Map<String, List<myStruct>> map2 = ...;
```

myStruct has 2 fields: a timestamp, and a number.

I need to make a new map3, with the keys found in map1 and map2. For each key, I need to add a new entry to the list of myStrcts every time map1 and map2's timestamp matches. The number should be equal to map1's number divided by map 2's number.

So for example if they each have 1 entry:

```
Map<String, List<myStruct>> map1 = < "Cat" , < <1pm, 10> <2pm, 6>, <3pm, 8>>;  
Map<String, List<myStruct>> map2 = < "Cat" , < <1pm, 5> <2pm, 2>, <3pm, 1>>;
```

then

```
Map<String, List<myStruct>> map3 = < "Cat" , < <1pm, 2> <2pm, 3>, <3pm, 8>>;
```

because for 1pm: 10/5 = 2, 2pm: 6/2 = 3, 3pm: 8/1 = 8.

I have tried playing around with lambda functions, but I can't come up with anything nice and efficient.

What I am doing now is iterating over each entry in map1, and then iterating over each timestamp of the myStructs - to compare it to the one in map2, and add the result to map 3 if the timestamps are equal. I'm trying to figure out a much more efficient solution.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've tried? That would help eliminate duplicate work.

Comment: Also, can the resulting number be a float value? What if the entries for 1pm are 8 and 5, resulting in 8/5. Do you want the float value or the int?

Comment: By the way, calling a [Class/Object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) a [‘struct’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) is confusing.

Comment: @lucasvw yes it should be a float. I just used those examples for simplicity.

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry about that! Noted for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the entries of `map1` and then do the division by streaming of the value of the map.

Check the code below

### SHORT CODE

`tmp` is the resulting `List<myStruct>`

```
 tmp = e.getValue()
        .stream()
        .map(struct -> new myStruct(struct.time, map2.get(e.getKey())
                                                           .stream()
                                                           .filter(x -> x.time.equals(struct.time))
                                                           .mapToInt(x -> struct.number / x.number)
                                                           .findFirst().getAsInt()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### LONG CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<myStruct>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<myStruct>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    myStruct one = new myStruct("1pm", 10);
    myStruct two = new myStruct("1pm", 5);
    myStruct thr = new myStruct("2pm", 6);
    myStruct fou = new myStruct("2pm", 2);
    myStruct fiv = new myStruct("3pm", 8);
    myStruct six = new myStruct("3pm", 1);

    map1.put("Cat", Arrays.asList(one, thr, fiv));
    map2.put("Cat", Arrays.asList(two, fou, six));

    Map<String, List<myStruct>> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);

    List<myStruct> tmp;

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<myStruct>> e : map1.entrySet()) {
         tmp = e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(struct -> new myStruct(struct.time, map2.get(e.getKey())
                                                                   .stream()
                                                                   .filter(x -> x.time.equals(struct.time))
                                                                   .mapToInt(x -> struct.number / x.number)
                                                                   .findFirst().getAsInt()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

         map3.put(e.getKey(), tmp);
    }

    System.out.println(map3); // {Cat=[<1pm, 2>, <2pm, 3>, <3pm, 8>]}
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this.

Comment: upvoted :) But I want to try it out first and see if I can come up with anything faster before accepting it.

Comment: @user101 No problem feel free to tell me if there's another way. I'm curious :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Here is my struct class, with timestamp as String field (Don't know which data type used in actual example, this is just for reference)

```
public class Mystruct 
{
    private String timeStamp;
    private int number;

    public Mystruct(String timeStamp,int number) 
    {
        this.timeStamp=timeStamp;
        this.number=number;
    }

    public Mystruct() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mystruct [timeStamp=" + timeStamp + ", number=" + number + "]";
    }

}
```

And Test class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Mystruct>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<Mystruct>>();
        Map<String, List<Mystruct>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<Mystruct>>();

        List<Mystruct> list1 = new ArrayList<Mystruct>();
        List<Mystruct> list2 = new ArrayList<Mystruct>();

        Mystruct struct1 = new Mystruct("1PM", 10);
        Mystruct struct2 = new Mystruct("2PM", 6);
        Mystruct struct3 = new Mystruct("3PM", 8);
        list1.add(struct1);
        list1.add(struct2);
        list1.add(struct3);

        Mystruct struct4 = new Mystruct("1PM", 5);
        Mystruct struct5 = new Mystruct("2PM", 2);
        Mystruct struct6 = new Mystruct("3PM", 1);
        list2.add(struct4);
        list2.add(struct5);
        list2.add(struct6);

        map1.put("Cat", list1);
        map2.put("Cat", list2);

        List<Mystruct> list3 = null;
        List<Mystruct> list4 = null;

        Map<String, List<Mystruct>> map3 = new HashMap<String, List<Mystruct>>();
        for (String key : map1.keySet()) 
        {
            if(map2.get(key)!=null)
            {
                list3=map1.get(key);
                list4=map2.get(key);

                List<Mystruct> structList = new ArrayList<Mystruct>();

                for(Mystruct outerStruct:list3)
                {
                    for(Mystruct innerStruct:list4)
                    {
                        if(outerStruct.getTimeStamp().equals(innerStruct.getTimeStamp()))
                        {
                            Mystruct structToStore=new Mystruct();
                            structToStore.setTimeStamp(outerStruct.getTimeStamp());
                            structToStore.setNumber(outerStruct.getNumber()/innerStruct.getNumber());
                            structList.add(structToStore);
                        }

                    }
                }
                map3.put(key, structList);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map3.toString());

    }

}
```

> OutPut:
>
> {Cat=[Mystruct [timeStamp=1PM, number=2], Mystruct [timeStamp=2PM,
>   number=3], Mystruct [timeStamp=3PM, number=8]]}

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it for now, but I need something much more efficient because I have a lot of entries and maps to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested operations here, merging the maps and merging the contained lists. First, I think trying to express the whole operation in one code block will become quite unreadable. Second, these `List<myStruct>`s are quite expensive to merge, especially if they tend to be large. So, one of these lists should be converted to a `Map<String,Integer>` (assuming `String` to be the type of the time stamp value) first, allowing an efficient lookup. Settling on that map, merging the other list with such a map to a resulting list can be expressed as

```
static List<myStruct> combine(List<myStruct> list, Map<String,Integer> map) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(a -> {
            Integer b=map.get(a.getTimeStamp());
            return b==null? null: new myStruct(a.getTimeStamp(), a.getNumber()/b);
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This implementation cares for time stamps not present in the other map. If there is always a corresponding entry, the method can be simplified to

```
static List<myStruct> combineSimplified(List<myStruct> list, Map<String,Integer> map) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(a -> new myStruct(a.getTimeStamp(), map.get(a.getTimeStamp())/a.getNumber()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using the list combining method, the map processing becomes as simple as

```
// preparation step
Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> prep=map1.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(myStruct::getTimeStamp, myStruct::getNumber))));

// final processing
Map<String, List<myStruct>> result = map2.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> combine(e.getValue(), prep.get(e.getKey()))));
```

Of course, you could inline the list combining method into the lambda expression, but I don’t recommend it. The readability would suffer significantly.